# Batch processing with PowerShell + Tesseract

Tags: powershell, tesseract

I want to batch-process all files within a folder with Tesseract and PowerShell:

`Convert.ps1`:

```
tesseract.exe -l deu C:\Users\Scan\img016.tif C:\Users\Scan\Out pdf
```

The result is: `Out.pdf`

The challange is:

- The script should consider all TIF-Files (File name can differ)
- The output PDF should contain the same file name (eg. `Image.tif` → `Image.pdf`)

Comment: hi tob, this is not a code writing service, try yourself and come back if you have a specific problem. check out the cmdlet `get-childitem`, that should be the key command you would be working with here

Answer (score 1):

Change into the scan folder first:

```
Set-Location 'C:\Users\Scan'
```

so that you can process the files without having to specify the full path (simplifies the output file handling).

Enumerate the TIFF files in that folder with `Get-ChildItem` and call `tesseract.exe` in a loop where you construct the output filename from the basename of the input filename:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.tif' | ForEach-Object {
    & 'tesseract.exe' -l deu $_.Name ($_.BaseName + '.pdf')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! I got it working with this Code

```
    # Set your Working directory
Set-Location 'C:\Users\Desktop\Scan'


Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.tif' | ForEach-Object {
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' -l deu $_.Name ($_.BaseName) pdf
}
```